# How to detect app(or mobile) is connected to Android Auto

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-auto

I searched, but could not get any answer
Is there any broadcast do detect when our phone is connected to Android Auto?

I have this code but that need to be run by some event.

```
public static boolean isCarUiMode(Context c) {
UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) c.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR) {
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Running in Car mode");
    return true;
} else {
    LogHelper.d(TAG, "Running on a non-Car mode");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Looking into the documentation on the UiModeManager, I found [ACTION_ENTER_CAR_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#ACTION_ENTER_CAR_MODE), as well as [ACTION_EXIT_CAR_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#ACTION_EXIT_CAR_MODE).

Using these, you can create and register a receiver in the manifest like so:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".CarModeReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.ENTER_CAR_MODE"/>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.EXIT_CAR_MODE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then in the implementation of the receiver, you can do something like this

```
public class CarModeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if (UiModeManager.ACTION_ENTER_CAR_MODE.equals(action)) {
        Log.d("CarModeReceiver", "Car Mode");
      } else if (UiModeManager.ACTION_EXIT_CAR_MODE.equals(action)) {
        Log.d("CarModeReceiver", "Non-Car Mode");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Those implicit broadcasts won't work if you target API level 26 or above, because ACTION_ENTER_CAR_MODE and ACTION_EXIT_CAR_MODE are not exempted from the background execution limits. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions